# VBScript to copy contents of a text file into an already existing Excel table

Tags: excel, text, vbscript

I am trying to use a VBScript to open, read and copy the contents of a text file into a pre-existing table in excel. Easy enough, right? I have just started learning VB (last week), and can't seem to really get it right. Here is what I gave so far.

```
Option Explicit

Dim objFileToRead
Dim objFSO
Dim objFileToWrite
Dim strFileText
Dim strFileCopy

Dim xl
Dim xlBook
Dim xlObject
Dim PasteCell

Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("Path",1)

    strFileText = objFileToRead.ReadAll()
    objFileToRead.Close

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
Set xlBook = xl.Workbooks.Open("Path")
Set xlObject = xl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set PasteCell = xlObject.Range("Table1[RequestId]")

    xl.Application.Visible = True
    xl.DisplayAlerts = False

    PasteCell.Value = strFileText
```

So the file is read, but placed completely into that first cell. So, is my thinking correct that I need to read the text file line by line? Or is there another way to do it. Since the text is tab delimited with about 7 columns, I would also need to to account for that. Is there another easier way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on what you actually want, you can do it without code. For example Data tab > From Text and in the connection properties you can select when the data is refreshed.

Comment: I'm calling a bunch of things with a batch file and would like to include this in the process, so I'd rather not have to leave my process half way through.

Comment: @JimGross Good Luck!